# Bootstrap justified-nav behavior on IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

If you look at the official example http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/ I noticed that on IE 11 the widths of the li elements are justified and share the same width ~ e.g. all li elements are about 190px). On Chrome/Webkit/Firefox Browsers etc. this varies (e.g. first li 175px, second li 192px etc.).

I have a project now where that exactly counts... Any ideas how to get the same behavior on IE then on Chrome/Webkit/Firefox?

EDIT: It depends on the width of the inner a element

Answer (score 0):

The key to give each cell (li element) equal width is to set the parent element to `display:table` and `table-layout:fixed`. And set the list elements width to 100%.

Add/Change the following declarations:

```
.nav-justified {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.nav-justified > li {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Edit: Added Demonstration Snippet**

```css
.nav-justified {
    /* New declarations*/
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

/* Use of greater selector specificity and !important is for demonstration purposes */
nav .nav-justified > li {
    /* New declarations*/
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```